using PST serverTimezone in jdbcUrl gives HibernateException when mysql-connector-java 8.0.32 is used
I am running a spring-boot 3.3.4 application.
here's my application property
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://server:port/database?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&tinyInt1isBit=false&serverTimezone=PST

when I run the application with mysql-connector-java 8.0.32, I get following Hibernate exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [xxxx]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
.
.
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
.
.
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)

But when I remove the serverTimezone=PST parameter from property OR use mysql-connector-java 8.0.16 with the property OR use serverTimeZone=America/Los_Angeles, the application runs.
Have they removed the support for PST and how do I check when such changes happen?
